# I am looking for help trying to create a .sh file to run steam games through wines windows player

Tags: bash, ubuntu, steam

I have a computer running Ubuntu with retropie (emulationstation) which i can create .sh files to run linux based steam games through as they can be directly installed onto the computer. I have installed wine in order to play the windows based games and while I can run the files by going into windows steam and clicking play, I am looking for a way to create a .sh file that will allow me to play them through retropie. I can post some of the stuff ive tried i just am struggling with the formatting.
Let me know if i need to post anything else or fix something!
EDIT: Heres some of the code ive tried, the first i thinks should run the executable through wine but i cant get anything to output, the second is some code i found online which watches for the game to close as well so it can exit clean.

```
#!/bin/bash
wine ~/PlayOnLinux\'s\ virtual\ drives/Steam/drive_c/Program\ 
Files/Steam/steamapps/common/MortalKombat_KompleteEdition/DiscContentPC/MKKE.exe

#! /bin/bash
appid=$1
procname=$2
PREFIX=/home/rig-cade/PlayOnLinux\'s\ virtual\ drives
STEAM="/home/rig-cade/.wine-steam/drive_c/Program Files/Steam/Steam.exe"
export WINEDEBUG=-all
export WINEPREFIX=$PREFIX

if [[ ((`pgrep -f steam.exe -c` == 0)) && ((`pgrep -f Steam.exe -c` == 0)) ]]; then
  optirun wine "$STEAM" -silent &
  sleep 20
fi
echo "Running game"
wine "$STEAM" steam://rungameid/$appid &
sleep 15
echo "Starting checks"
status=`pgrep -f $procname -c`
if (( "$status" > 1 )); then
  while (( "$status" > 1 )); do
    sleep 5
    status=`pgrep -f $procname -c`
  done
  wine "$STEAM" -shutdown &
fi
echo "Exiting"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please do post the code you have; without that, there's no real answer to your question that doesn't involve writing the code for you, and that's not the purpose of StackOverflow (nor really possible with the few specs you've posted). Good luck with your project!

Comment: I think i got the code fixed to look nice now, hopefully that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure and I will test once I get done with work in a couple hours, but AFAIK the Steam URL protocol cannot be used with the command-line and so when you try this Steam is likely throwing a parsing error. If you add `-console` after `-silent` it should enable the Console tab and allow you to see an error message if you open the client.

Instead try one of

- Only using the browser protocol without the "$STEAM" part so it's not trying to pass it as an argument to the client.
- Using the [Steam Command-line parameter](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Command_Line_Options#Command-line_parameters_3) `-applaunch {appid}`,
  where {appid} is replaced with the appid of the game to be run as you were already trying to do.

Comment: It turns out the game i was trying to run simply wasnt working with the computer. I switched games and got it to work! Thanks for the help

Comment: Very welcome :) Glad you got it working.

Sorry I'm so slow -- I saw this, but was still learning to use the site and I just found it again. Lmao.